# Array Saving in form

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

So I am using just a very simple Javascript array for example

```
var dateArray = []

function datePush() {
  dateArray.push(/*Date(s) Needed To Be Pushed*/);
}
```

I do not have any problems with the code and it pushing to the array but I would like to know if there is a way to save pushes to an array such as...

**Monday @ 13:00**

I open "add.html"

```
var dateArray = ["01/02/03"]
```

I push the following:

```
var dateArray = ["01/02/03", "02/03/04"]
```

Which this is all great but now I close "add.html"

**Monday @ 15:00**

I reopen "add.html" and the pushed data from before is not saved...

```
//Instead of having the array with
var dateArray = ["01/02/03", "02/03/04"]
// I have the array with
var dateArray = ["01/02/03"]
```

In short I just want to know if there is a concrete method that as soon as I push the data to the array that the array will indefinitely update with the information which I could call later and the data not be erased once the browser session is closed. And If this requires I am not proficient with PHP (Yeah, I am very sorry!), so if the only viable solution to this would be PHP could you give me an example on how this would be done? :)

***Also I must add that MySql can not be used for this, My ISP does not allow server hosting what so ever and this will be accessed out of my network and all data has to be stored on my webhost***

Comment: I guess the only way is to use cookies.

Comment: PHP after my minimum reading and understanding seems like it might be able to do the trick! So I guess maybe to see if someone could post a method or me just trying fail after fail until I figure it out! lol

Comment: You can user cookie to save the data in your own browser and if you want to use the array globally you should use php and save the data into database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this using just javascript, you can use cookies. They can store your data for specified period of time (you set this period). If you can use php for implementing this task there are no limitations on how you can do this).

Comment: I am just wondering is there a set fine way to use the post method to send and save the data in the javascript array? If so could you just tell me what I would need to search for in an API guide?

Comment: If you can use php and can't use any database you can keep your data in a plain text file. Try to read about how to read and write files in php. Then on the client you can send you array to the server. On the server you read this data and save it in the text file. Next time when you open your webpage, on the server you can read this data from the text file and send to the client.

Comment: I shall get onto it tomorrow during my 10 hour ride to Dallas lol, thanks for the information! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use cookies with PHP like the commenter suggested, you can serialize your array and use the setcookie method.

it goes setcookie(cookieName, cookieValue, time() + howLongTheCookieLasts)

```
setcookie('dateCookie', serialize($dateArray), time() + 3600) //saves for one hour
```

Unserialize the cookie to access your array

```
$dataArray = unserialize($_COOKIE['dateCookie']);
```

Further references...

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: is there a way to save cookies to a server and set time to infinite? Might I add this is not the best idea to solve this, but I will need to access the data for as long as I use this and I would need to access on every computer I use to query and post.

Comment: You can set the cookie to not expire for a very long time. However, if this data needs to be viewed by more than one user then you most certainly shouldn't use cookies. If you need to view the same data on different computers this may be something you should store in a database instead.

Comment: Would you know of any DB I could use? It can not be hosted by me because of ISP issues, I would love to try in MySQL but when contacting my ISP to try to get it to work something with internal IP's and External IP's with their systems would not allow me to do it unless I purchased a "Direct Static IP" so all of that is out the window.

Comment: You could try a database on a cloud service like Azure, AWS, MongoLab.